# How to rewrite folder path to controller path using .htaccess file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I am working on Codeigniter and I have not enough knowledge of .htaccess file. I need a simple solution for my project.

I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/ziraf/assets/pdf_docs/1513420922.pdf
```

and I have a user controller and its path like this.

```
http://localhost/ziraf/user/readData/12
```

So whenever a user hits `http://localhost/ziraf/assets/pdf_docs/1513420922.pdf` in the browser then I want to call `http://localhost/ziraf/user/readData/12` in the background using the .htaccess file. I have tried 301 redirect code but it is not working.

Comment: But what is the logic of the relation of those 2 URLS? Where does the 12 come from?

Comment: when user requests for a file by URL `1513420922.pdf` it will access in `readData` method of user controller where 12 will be replaced by  `1513420922.pdf`. After I need to check session in  `readData` method if the session is active then I want to show `1513420922.pdf` file otherwise want to redirect on the login page.

Comment: `http://localhost/ziraf/user/readData/here_will_be_file_name` and in user controller my function will look like this. `public function readData($pdffile){   echo $pdffile; }` where `$pdffile` value will be `1513420922.pdf`. Hope you will undrastand.

Comment: why need `readData` method to check session , u can check ur session in your `pdf_docs` method also, if found show pdf otherwise show 404

Comment: `pdf_docs` is not a method it is folder name located in assets directory